# How to prove convergence of a summation

Tags: calculus, limits

> Evaluate $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(\sum_{k=2}^n\frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{k(\log k)^2}\right)=L$$

My approach
$$L=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left((\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})\sum_{k=2}^n\frac{1}{k(\log k)^2}\right)$$ Now $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}=0$$ is finite and also
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{k=2}^{n}\frac{1}{k(\log k)^2}$$ is finite and equal to $1.92$, approx.

So we can break the limit into two parts as limit of both sub parts is finite. **Hence the answer is $0$, which is also the correct answer.**

But my doubt is how to prove that $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{k=2}^{n}\frac{1}{k(\log k)^2}=1.92$$ rather I need to prove that it converges to a finite number.

I checked the value $1.92$ from wolframaplha but couldn't do it by hand.

I also haven't learnt Limit Comparison Test until now.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Are you aware of the [integral test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence) or [Cauchy condensation test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test)?

Comment: @SangchulLee im a high schooler :)

Comment: The integral test is a very versatile result to be added to your calculus toolbox! It is also very intuitive interpretation in terms of areas. You may give it a read to the linked article.

Comment: Wolframalpha doesn't give 1.92 but 2.10974

Comment: @AnneBauval pls see the attachment...is my WA crashed or what??

Comment: Hey @MathStackexchangeIsVeryBad ! Yesterday this sum was posted here [mathematics Problems](https://www.instagram.com/p/Co4TvnUJ47b/?utm_source=ig_web_copy_link)

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHfAT.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the suggested integral test the last infinite sum (minus the $k=2$ term, which is of minor importance for this test) is upper-bounded by
$$\int_2^\infty\frac1{k\log^2k}\,dk=[-1/\log k]_2^\infty<\infty$$
and so the last infinite sum converges.

Comment: Thank you..just one more question...is the answer of the above limit $0$... as some of my homies are saying that $0$ is wrong...but 
I think its correct $?$

Comment: @MathStackexchangeIsVeryBad Your proof is correct and your result is correct. :)

Comment: Hey...is this true?? $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}=0$$ wolframaplha shows that it's value if infinity...if yes how is my answer correct $?$ @Parcly Taxel

Comment: @MathStackexchangeIsVeryBad You input it wrong. It is 0.